# How to best apply `skimage.util.apply_parallel` to remove small objects in large datasets?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

For a [study where I'm processing a fairly large cohort of tomographically scanned teeth](https://github.com/habi/zmk-tooth-cohort) I'd like to implement a cropping function to extract each tooth from its surroundings.
For this I'm using `scipy.ndimage.find_objects(thresholded_data)[0]` and follow what's outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html).

To reliably extract the tooth from the full dataset I need to remove small objects from the thresholded data prior to extracting the tooth with `find_object`.
I achieve this with

```py
def cropper(image, threshold=66):
  thresholded = image > threshold
  despeckled = skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(thresholded, min_size=500)
  cropdimensions = scipy.ndimage.find_objects(despeckled)[0]
  return(image[cropdimensions])
```

My datasets are quite large (each with a size of around 4000 x 1632 x 1632 voxels) and I'm using `dask` to store a representation of the full datasets on disk.
To make my function above work I thus have to deliberately use `.compute()` at the beginning to load the full dataset into RAM.
I thought I should be able to apply the `skimage.util.apply_parallel` function for speeding up my processing (and making it possible to run on a machine with less than 196 GB of RAM which I fortunately have).

If I read the documentation correclty, it seems that I can 'simply' expand my function and use the code below.

```py
def cropper(image, threshold=66):
    thresholded = image > threshold
    despeckled = skimage.util.apply_parallel(skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects,
                                             thresholded,
                                             extra_keywords={'min_size': 500})
    cropdimensions = skimage.util.apply_parallel(scipy.ndimage.find_objects,
                                                 thresholded)
    cropdimensions = cropdimensions[0]
    return(image[cropdimensions])
```

But I get an `AttributeError`that a `'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'`.
If I remove the `find_objects`, I can get out the despeckled image like so

```py
def cropper(image, threshold=66):
    thresholded = image > threshold
    despeckled = skimage.util.apply_parallel(skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects,
                                             thresholded,
                                             extra_keywords={'min_size': 500})
    return(despeckled)
```

Can I not use two consecutive `apply_parallel`s in the same function?

Answer (score 0):

After a while of debugging; Obviously you *can't*, because you're *not* using `skimage` to find the object!
If you change the relevant line to `cropdimensions = scipy.ndimage.find_objects(despeckled)[0]` it works as expected, you silly!